# Is there any general rule of thumb that can be followed for where and when to add commas and full stops?

Tags: punctuation, commas, periods

I always mess up with my writing by adding commas and full stops (periods) in the wrong places. Is there any rule of thumb or some other way that I can follow to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ElendilTheTall has great advice regarding placing commas when you pause when reading a sentence aloud. The only thing I feel needs to be added to that answer is to not *overuse* commas; that is, don't use a comma when you need a period.

Each sentence sentence normally should not have two main clauses separated by a mere comma. For example:

> I love to eat ice cream, on hot summer days I always buy some.

This is incorrect, because there's two distinct thoughts and two verbs here ("I love" and "I buy"). The correct version would be:

> I love to eat ice cream. I always buy some on hot summer days.

Alternatively, since these two thoughts are closely related you could use a semicolon instead of a period:

> I love to eat ice cream; on hot summer days I always buy some.

Note how in this case you would not capitalize the letter after the semicolon, because it is *not* the first letter of a new sentence.

**EDIT:** What I'm trying to help you avoid is creating [run-on sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence), which can happen when you use a comma when you should use a period. This is known as a [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

**EDIT 2:** User psmears pointed out another error in my explanation; my explanation was too simplistic and excluded some perfectly acceptable sentences.  You can join two main clauses with a [coordinating conjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjunction#Coordinating_conjunctions). User psmears gives the example,

> I like Mary and I hate John.

In this case there's two clear main clauses, each with their own finite verb ("like" and "hate"). However, while this is perfectly acceptable for short, closely relayed clauses, it can quickly lead to run-ons if you're not careful:

> I like my coworker Mary from the accounting department but I hate my other coworker John from engineering because John always thinks he's better than everyone else and he always corrects other people's grammar but I really don't think he speaks very well and when someone criticizes other people for something they themselves are guilty of that's called being hypocritical and I don't like people who act like that.

Comment: @josh: you are correct, i usually add to many commas.

Comment: And that's a case where it should be a semicolon instead of a comma. :-)

Comment: (Well, unless you said "You are correct that I usually add to many commas")

Comment: @Josh: "You should generally not have two verbs per sentence" - But in "I *love* to *eat* ice cream" we already have two verbs. Your suggestion is good for simple sentences, but it doesn't seem to work for complex ones with many clauses. It is in that kind of sentences that you would have more than one verbs: "As for those who *like* to *place* a lot of commas in the sentence and *think* that they *do* the right in acting that way, I would *tell* them that each sentence should *be* one complete thought, with a noun and a verb, and, therefore, there should *be* generally only 1 verb in it."

Comment: Well in "I love to eat ice cream", `love` is the verb, `to eat` is an infinitive. But I can see that it's still a verb... What's the word I'm looking for then? I'll correct my answer... Do you understand what I mean to say?

Comment: @brilliant for example, your sentence has only one "verb", `would`: "I would tell". But if "verb" isn't the word I'm search for, what is?

Comment: I think you mean to say that a sentence normally should not have two main clauses separated by a mere comma.

Comment: Thanks @Cerberus, I corrected that, that's a far better explanation.

Comment: Cool, you already got my vote. Oops, was "cool" a main clause?

Comment: @Cerberus and @brilliant, this [led me to a question of my own](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9463/is-there-a-word-for-the-primary-verb-in-a-clause)

Comment: @Josh: I think you are looking for *finite verb*, because a normal clause has only one finite verb. But note that there are definite exceptions to your rule, like this: *I called her, spoke to her, touched her*.

Comment: @Cerberus: We're talking about the English language; there's *always* exceptions! `;-)`

Comment: @Josh: True! Come to think about it, I think the usual definition says "independent sentence".

Comment: @Josh: I'm still not sure this answer is quite right (though the basic idea is sound) - the issue is that it's fine to join two otherwise independent sentences with a (coordinating) conjunction: "I like Mary and I hate John" - both verbs are finite; neither is more "main" than the other.

Comment: @psmears: I agree... I'll add what you mentioned, thanks. After losing nearly an hour delving into wikipedia on this issue, I was still unclear on how to describe this in a clear, concise rule. Of course the example you provided is fine and proper, but conjunctions can quickly lead to run-ons. "I like Mary and I hate John because he's always mean to me and I don't like people who are mean to me and I think that people should be nice to each other all the time!"

Answer (score 7):

Write a sentence, then read it back to yourself. If at any point you feel the need to pause, that's where you put a comma. Once you have practiced like this for a while, you will be able to put them in as you write.

Full stops go only at the end of sentences; it's that simple.