# Is there a word for the "primary" verb in a clause?

Tags: verbs, terminology

In [an answer to another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9452/is-there-any-general-rule-of-thumb-that-can-be-followed-for-where-and-when-to-add/9458#9458), I erroneously said:

> Each sentence sentence normally be one complete thought, with a noun and a verb. You should generally not have two verbs per sentence

What I was trying to say was that each sentence should have one... "primary verb", but I'm looking for the actual term to describe this. I am sure "primary verb" is not it.

As an example, user brilliant commented on that question and gave this example:

> As for those who like to place a lot of commas in the sentence and think that they do the right in acting that way, I would tell them that each sentence should be one complete thought, with a noun and a verb, and, therefore, there should be generally only one verb in it.

In that sentence, there's a lot of verbs... What is the way to describe the verb "would", as used in "I would tell", and only that verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *finite verb*, as opposed to participles and infinitives.

Comment: Ah ha, that seems to be exactly it. Thanks *again!*

Comment: @Josh: Wait, I misread your question... I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ok. His comment confuses me. Maybe I don't mean "tell", maybe I mean "would". I am pretty sure I am looking for the finite verb. In your examples I am looking for "heard" and "like"

Comment: @Josh: Right, those are the finite verbs.